# How to Pull All Downloads from a Website and Reiterate Over All Options and Download Every Option with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

So I have a website that allows me to select options from within the website. 
I have to go in and download all of the `.csv` and `.txt` files that are existential in the website. 
I generally know the parameters, but I need to have it where all files are downloaded. 
I also need it to be dynamic and check for when new files become available. There is no API for the website, so I have been using Selenium and Python to automate a download from the website. 
I have been successful in getting a file to download. However, I would like to iterate the option over all indexes from a drop down menu item. Please see the image below:

[image]

I know the ID and XPATH for it as `XPATH = //*[@id='reportingAdminCode']` This is for the Reporting Admin Field. The `Report` field is always fixed to the following:

```
          # Student Data File (Complete) Index 4 NEEDED FOR REPORT XPATH = //*[@id='reportTypeSelected']/option[5]
          element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='reportTypeSelected']/option[5]")))
          element.click();
          time.sleep(3)
```

When I hit the Search button based off of criteria, the names are always different with the exception of a year in the name sometimes and certain naming schemes that don't seem to be constant. Furthermore, it also seems that there are multiple final versions. So I am really trying to come up with a process that will download them all at once, and then zip them up and compress them on the next download. Kind of like a log rotation within Linux but for downloading all of the files at once. When the search parameters are properly filled I get the following ability to select something:

Example
[image]

What could be done to get all downloads at once?
You can find the html source page here: [link](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/State-Assessments/Texas/Sources/tx-login_ets_source_page.html)

Comment: You should consider the following: 1. Data mining is often against the website TOS, and is a good way to get blacklisted. 2. Have a look at the `wget` package for Python.

Comment: cool thanks @SiKing I appreciate the reference.